# remove background plot lines in pyplot.hist()

Tags: python, histogram

How do I remove the background lines on this matplotlib histogram example?

[Link to matplotlib tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pyplots/pyplot_text.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pyplots-pyplot-text-py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change `plt.grid(True)` to `plt.grid(False)` in the sample code?